# Check if several points are in path - JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a project and I need to check if several points, X Y coordinates, on a canvas are in a defined path.  Basically I want to use something like `.isPointInPath(x,y)`, but with a range of pixels.  What I am trying to do is check the points `20, 30 - 26, 30`.

- Is there an existing method to accomplish this?
- If not, does this mean I have to check each individual point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just the built in function you have to check each and every point.

You could check just the end, but crescent-shaped paths (etc) would fail.

Things would get a little better if you implement a `segment-intersects-path` algorithm (or `line-intersects-path`, if you throw out points that are not on the segment you want).

Then you check for path intersections between `(20, 30)` and `(26, 30)`. If those two points are in the path and there are zero line/segment intersections with the path, then you know the entire line from `(20, 30)` to `(26, 30)` is in the path.

Comment: Since this is a basic project, I'll just go with checking individual points that are 10px apart.  If I decide to take it further, I will probably make an algorithm to handle it.